# How user apps installed from Play Store get update from Get Apps in Xiaomi MIUI 12

Tags: android-11, redmi-note-10-pro, miui-12.5

I am using Redmi Note 10 Pro with MIUI 12.5.8 Android 11 running on it. The device has two official application providers, one is Google's Play Store and other is Xiaomi Get Apps. My issue is that, I installed whatsapp from Play Store. Now, it shows that whastapp has an update under Settings-System apps updater-Otherapps, on clicking which will load Get Apps.
I checked play store, and there's no update showing. Similarly, for Zoom app, update available both from Play Store and Get Apps.

How Play Store installed app got an update from Get Apps?

Comment: Android as an OS does not care from where an app comes it installs. And each app store can check if there is a app of the same packageName available that has a higher versionCode in it's `AndroidManifest.xml`.  Hopefully the app store has also checked that the app signatures are the same/compatible, otherwise the app will fail if you try to install it. See also my answer on a very similar question about Samsung Galaxy Store: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234390/2241

Comment: In addition to Robert's comment, compared to alternative markets, [updates on the Play Store can take a few days to reach users](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191587/44325) due to its roll-out policy and magnitude.